# Prove that the direct product of $2$ subgroups is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, direct-product

I have an exercise where I am tasked to prove that for $2$ subgroups $K < G$ and $J < H$ of $2$ groups $G,H$ the following is a subgroup: $$K \times J \subset G \times H$$

I believe I have done so, though I would appreciate some verification that my reasoning is correct.

---

**Proof**

The set $K \times J$ is defined as $\{ (k,j) \mid k \in K, j \in J\}$ where $K < G$ and $J< H$. We must show closure of products and inverses in $K \times J$ to show $K \times J < G \times H$.

1. Let $(k,j)$, $(k',j') \in K \times J$. Then we have $$(k,j)(k',j') = (kk', jj') \in K \times J$$ Since $kk' \in K$ and $jj' \in J$
2. Let $k^{-1} \in K$ and $j^{-1} \in J$ Then we have:$$(k,j)(k^{-1},j^{-1}) = (kk^{-1}, jj^{-1}) = (e,e)$$ $$(k^{-1},j^{-1})(k,j) = (k^{-1}k, j^{-1}j) = (e,e)$$ Since $kk^{-1} = k^{-1}k = e \in K$ and $jj^{-1} = j^{-1}j = e \in J$. Thus $(k^{-1},j^{-1}) \in K \times J$. Hence $(K \times J) < G \times H$. $\square$

Does this look alright?

Comment: "Thus $(k^{-1},j^{-1}) \in K \times J$": well, this is not a direct consequence of the previuos part, which rather shows that $(k,j)^{-1}=(k^{-1},j^{-1})$; the membership $(k^{-1},j^{-1}) \in K \times J$ comes just from $K$ and $J$ being groups.

Comment: @fitzcarraldo Oh okay thanks. I suspected as much but it seemed "too easy" and I know in real math there is no such thing - if it works it works, if it's true it's true - but this problem having been selected as an exercise made me reconsider that suspicion. I'll try to temper that nagging voice that says "it can't be so simple..."

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

You need to show that the set is a nonempty subset in order to use the two-step subgroup test. Luckily, this is trivial: $(e_G, e_H)\in K\times J$ and $K\subseteq G$ & $J\subseteq H$ imply $K\times J\subseteq G\times H$.

Comment: Oh yes of course. I keep defaulting back to the $2$ criteria that have been laid out in the definition of a subgroup in my text but keep forgetting that all the examples start with showing the subgroup is nonempty. Thank you Shuan, I will need to drill that down in my mind.

Comment: You're welcome, @NumericalDisintegration.